# Evaluating a Riemann-Stieltjes Integral with $d\lceil x^2\rceil$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I have some troubles evaluating this integral. It confuses me how to use the definition  with the function $\lceil x^2\rceil $.
 $$\int_{0}^{5}x d(\lceil x^2\rceil)$$

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've noted that $\lceil x^2\rceil$ has a jump in every $x=\sqrt{ n }$. Then, I thought in spliting the integral in smaller integrals.

Comment: This should be doable directly from the definition. The integrator function $\lceil x^2\rceil $ is constant except for at $x=\sqrt{n}$. It might help to know what you have already tried.

Comment: Hint: Use Integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $n \leq x^2<n+1 \iff \sqrt{n}\leq x < \sqrt{n+1}$

Then, the integrator is constant everywhere except for $x=\sqrt{n}$ where it has a jump ($\alpha$ will be used to denote the jump). Then, by definition.

$$\int_{0}^{5}x d(\lceil x^2\rceil) = \sum_{n=1}^{25} \sqrt{{n}}  (\alpha_{n}-\alpha_{n-1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{25} \sqrt{{n}}$$

because $\alpha_{n}-\alpha_{n-1} = n+1-n =1$.

Comment: $\lceil x^2 \rceil$ is continuous from the left at $x = 5$, $n$ in the sums should run from $1$ to $24$.